# docker desktop wsl 2 backend has stopped unexpectedly

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, wsl-2, docker-desktop

I am facing issue with Docker desktop. it is getting crashed in 15-20 min.

Docker Desktop 4.3.2
Docker 20.10.11
Windows 10 PRO

reference link: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/12477

Answer (score 1):

I met that problem too, but that's when I start a relatively big image/container, and don't see many useful solutions on the community.

One tutorial that I follow is, add some config documents to limit the RAM use of the WSL-2, and restart my PC, it seems to work.

User Win+R, then enter '%UserProfile%' to enter the user dictionary in Windows, create a file: '.wslconfig', and then edit the file as follows:

```
[wsl2]
memory=8GB
swap=0
localhostForwarding=true
```

The 'memory' should be edited by the condition of our laptops, I used 4GB in my one. Then restart the PC.

I'm new to Docker, don't know whether it's the right solution, but it seems work in my laptop:D Hope that can help someone meet the same problem.